# Laravel, How to extend class inside vendor?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Barryvdh laravel Debugbar, and I want to extend the class inside LaravelDebugBar in \vendor\barryvdh\laravel-debugbar\src\LaravelDebugBar.php. I just want to override one function there. How do I extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend like this:

`YourOwnClass extend Barryvdh\Debugbar\LaravelDebugbar`

But also, you need build you own ServiceProvider for YourOwnClass, and replace in app config

`Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider`

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a ServiceProvider.php for that? What codes do I put in there?

Comment: Just copy ServiceProvider of DubugBar, and register your class instead of LaravelDebugBar in register method

Comment: Another question. Do I have to declare the class this way: "class ServiceProvider extends \Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"?

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? 
There is hardly any explanation.

Comment: I understand it perfectly, I was just surprised that there is no actually code in the accepted answer.

A more detailed example would be a lot better.